# Selecting all sub children when Checkbox of child is checked in treeview using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am using this jquery to select all the children when a parent is clicked and it is working fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div[id $= Tree_Index]").find("input[type=checkbox]:first").click(function () { 
        $(this).closest("div").find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

Now, if i have a sub child for a child, i want to select all the sub children when a child is selected. How can I achieve this in jquery.

```
<div style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;" class="tree" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctlEsnSearchByServices$Treecontrol_Left_0$Tree_Index','t1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c')"><img style="border-width:0;" alt="Collapse Clinics" src="/WebResource.axd?d=_533LbcrYzxclETTqT9E9lbjpoP9iiSVLn9WP908dD96sH9D2JXH4BN8Q2OdATM4TYJU67kfDSnJQpffp_ITMVu3Y839pir-IzEhB41mqu6U8EWb0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></a></td><td class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_1"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn0CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn0CheckBox"><span id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indext0" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_0">Clinics</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctlEsnSearchByServices$Treecontrol_Left_0$Tree_Index','t1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c\\3f2cfef3-2466-48f7-84aa-82cd23bc3249')"><img style="border-width:0;" alt="Collapse GP Clinics" src="/WebResource.axd?d=PtoZaOE4OJ68kA17eB1Ru-nLDbZ-ilvB8z5abVJ8BfKZp0iKKZ8iPpsV8tJ5bLWmNAAyfP3gCpxQRyrUtuHqeJKGILYd8Nbb3deoYK17HD9ZYyeS0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></a></td><td class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_1"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn1CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn1CheckBox"><span id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indext1" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_0">GP Clinics</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=J9BSVEmYJ2R79DzKPp_KwudhxkmRYjt31taLGpqjHFuG3gyciimdNIz2hfef3rMTcgKKF9rZcFetwoS-fvXnw3uYWh88CZ98-dNXPYEoMwTaffwZ0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_1"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn2CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn2CheckBox"><span id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indext2" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_0">CDMP Participating Clinics</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=J9BSVEmYJ2R79DzKPp_KwudhxkmRYjt31taLGpqjHFuG3gyciimdNIz2hfef3rMTcgKKF9rZcFetwoS-fvXnw3uYWh88CZ98-dNXPYEoMwTaffwZ0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_1"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn3CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn3CheckBox"><span id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indext3" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_0">CHAS Participating Clinics - Dental</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=J9BSVEmYJ2R79DzKPp_KwudhxkmRYjt31taLGpqjHFuG3gyciimdNIz2hfef3rMTcgKKF9rZcFetwoS-fvXnw3uYWh88CZ98-dNXPYEoMwTaffwZ0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_1"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn4CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn4CheckBox"><span id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indext4" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_0">CHAS Participating Clinics &ndash; Medical</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=J9BSVEmYJ2R79DzKPp_KwudhxkmRYjt31taLGpqjHFuG3gyciimdNIz2hfef3rMTcgKKF9rZcFetwoS-fvXnw3uYWh88CZ98-dNXPYEoMwTaffwZ0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_1"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn5CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn5CheckBox"><span id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indext5" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_0">IDAPE/ElderShield Disability Assessors</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=J9BSVEmYJ2R79DzKPp_KwudhxkmRYjt31taLGpqjHFuG3gyciimdNIz2hfef3rMTcgKKF9rZcFetwoS-fvXnw3uYWh88CZ98-dNXPYEoMwTaffwZ0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=BOvsSO2B3BKMupOSRxbma89ER-i_r1FrqfnVsgVq_QiVog3IJUebdD29i4BVAo26-lbJh_BLXmsQGU_VArXhNt6ejiWJk87whzKer6ts-_kM9Vt90&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_1"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn6CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn6CheckBox"><span id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indext6" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_0">Other GP Clinics</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctlEsnSearchByServices$Treecontrol_Left_0$Tree_Index','t1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c\\2fb1d7f3-1a31-4846-ab0c-76adbccf008c')"><img style="border-width:0;" alt="Collapse Other Clinics" src="/WebResource.axd?d=PtoZaOE4OJ68kA17eB1Ru-nLDbZ-ilvB8z5abVJ8BfKZp0iKKZ8iPpsV8tJ5bLWmNAAyfP3gCpxQRyrUtuHqeJKGILYd8Nbb3deoYK17HD9ZYyeS0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></a></td><td class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_1"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn7CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn7CheckBox"><span id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indext7" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_0">Other Clinics</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=J9BSVEmYJ2R79DzKPp_KwudhxkmRYjt31taLGpqjHFuG3gyciimdNIz2hfef3rMTcgKKF9rZcFetwoS-fvXnw3uYWh88CZ98-dNXPYEoMwTaffwZ0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_1"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn8CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn8CheckBox"><span id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indext8" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_0">Community Geriatric Clinics</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=J9BSVEmYJ2R79DzKPp_KwudhxkmRYjt31taLGpqjHFuG3gyciimdNIz2hfef3rMTcgKKF9rZcFetwoS-fvXnw3uYWh88CZ98-dNXPYEoMwTaffwZ0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_1"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn9CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn9CheckBox"><span id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indext9" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_0">Community VWO Clinics</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=J9BSVEmYJ2R79DzKPp_KwudhxkmRYjt31taLGpqjHFuG3gyciimdNIz2hfef3rMTcgKKF9rZcFetwoS-fvXnw3uYWh88CZ98-dNXPYEoMwTaffwZ0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_1"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn10CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn10CheckBox"><span id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indext10" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_0">Counselling Service</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=J9BSVEmYJ2R79DzKPp_KwudhxkmRYjt31taLGpqjHFuG3gyciimdNIz2hfef3rMTcgKKF9rZcFetwoS-fvXnw3uYWh88CZ98-dNXPYEoMwTaffwZ0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_1"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn11CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn11CheckBox"><span id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indext11" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_0">Physiotherapy Service</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=J9BSVEmYJ2R79DzKPp_KwudhxkmRYjt31taLGpqjHFuG3gyciimdNIz2hfef3rMTcgKKF9rZcFetwoS-fvXnw3uYWh88CZ98-dNXPYEoMwTaffwZ0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_1"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn12CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn12CheckBox"><span id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indext12" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_0">Private Medical Centres</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=J9BSVEmYJ2R79DzKPp_KwudhxkmRYjt31taLGpqjHFuG3gyciimdNIz2hfef3rMTcgKKF9rZcFetwoS-fvXnw3uYWh88CZ98-dNXPYEoMwTaffwZ0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=BOvsSO2B3BKMupOSRxbma89ER-i_r1FrqfnVsgVq_QiVog3IJUebdD29i4BVAo26-lbJh_BLXmsQGU_VArXhNt6ejiWJk87whzKer6ts-_kM9Vt90&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_1"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn13CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn13CheckBox"><span id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indext13" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_0">Psychiatric Outpatient Rehabilitation Centres</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=BOvsSO2B3BKMupOSRxbma89ER-i_r1FrqfnVsgVq_QiVog3IJUebdD29i4BVAo26-lbJh_BLXmsQGU_VArXhNt6ejiWJk87whzKer6ts-_kM9Vt90&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_1"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn14CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indexn14CheckBox"><span id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Indext14" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_Treecontrol_Left_0_Tree_Index_0">Polyclinics</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FRdAz/1/)**

Your markup is so complex. So, the best way to make a relation between
your **parents** and **childs** is using **attributes** instead of
hierarchy of your HTML.

Consider the following markup:

```
<div><input type="checkbox" data-rel="parent" data-id="1" />Parent 1</div>
<div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" data-rel="child" data-id="1" />Child 1.1</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" data-rel="child" data-id="1" />Child 1.2</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" data-rel="child" data-id="1" />Child 1.3</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" data-rel="child" data-id="1" />Child 1.4</div>
</div>

<div><input type="checkbox" data-rel="parent" data-id="2" />Parent 2</div>
<div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" data-rel="child" data-id="2" />Child 2.1</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" data-rel="child" data-id="2" />Child 2.2</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" data-rel="child" data-id="2" />Child 2.3</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" data-rel="child" data-id="2" />Child 2.4</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I make a relation between parents and child
with `data-rel` and `data-id` attributes.

Then in your jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // whenever the parent checkbox changed
    $(':checkbox[data-rel="parent"]').on('change', function () {
        // get the current group by data-id attribute
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        // get childs checkboxes within the current group
        $(':checkbox[data-rel="child"][data-id="' + id + '"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

---

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CRkJG/2/)**

Because you said that you can't change your markup (as it's a controller in ASP.net), here
is the solution to your markup:

```
$(function () {
    $('.tree').on('change', ':checkbox', function () {
        var checked = this.checked;
        var $elem = $(this).closest('table');
        var depth = $elem.find('div').length;
        var $childs = $elem.nextAll('table');
        $childs.each(function () {
            var $child = $(this);
            var d = $child.find('div').length;
            if (d <= depth) {
                return false;
            }

            $child.find(':checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
        });
    });
});
```

- `[!]` Don't forget to check the [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CRkJG/2/).

Comment: The HTML in question, is rendered from a asp.net treeview control. And I don't think the attributes which you have used can be put in that control. I need a solution for the HTML that is rendered for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Anuya OK, I add a solution for working with your markup `;)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `prop()` and change event (better than click) instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div[id $= Tree_Index]").find("input[type=checkbox]:first").change(function () {
        $(this).closest("div").find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is not working. Even when clicking the parent checkbox, it does not select the child nodes which was working with the code in question.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ACyXQ/  Please consider to fix your code (posting only relevant because your code is unreadable and html is not valid). BTW, remove all this inline CSS which is completly useless regarding your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard with the markup you have, webforms is well know for producing horrible markup like this. The main problem is the hierarchical nature of the tree view is not actually reflected in a hierarchy in the markup. Having said that, the following javascript is a way of achieving the result you are looking for.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sLngS/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input:checkbox").change(function () {
           var currentLevel = $(this).parents('tr').children('td').length;
           var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
            $('tr').each(function(index, value){
                var level = $('td',this).length;
                if (level >= (currentLevel + 1)){
                    $("input:checkbox", this).prop('checked', isChecked);
                }
            })
        });            
    });
```